# How can I add a restart button for my snake game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to coding and I'm following some tutorials. I want to add a button that resets the game when the snake collides or hits the wall. I don't want to rely on the refresh button on browsers, I want to make a  reset button specifically for the game. How will I code that? I would appreciate your help thanks!

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("Snake");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

//box unit 
var box = 32;

// Background and styling 

var ground = new Image();
ground.src = "images/ground.png";

var foodImg = new Image();
foodImg.src = "images/food.png";

// Snake Array

var snake = [];
snake[0] = {
    x: 9 * box,
    y: 10 * box
}

// create the food

let food = {
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 17 + 1) * box,
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 15 + 3) * box
}

//Event Listener to control the snake.

var d;

document.addEventListener("keydown", direction);

function direction(event) {

    if ((event.key == 'ArrowLeft' || event.key == 'a' || event.key == 'A') && d != "RIGHT") {
        d = "LEFT";
    } else if ((event.key == 'ArrowUp' || event.key == 'w' || event.key == 'W') && d != "DOWN") {
        d = "UP";
    } else if ((event.key == 'ArrowRight' || event.key == 'd' || event.key == 'D') && d != "LEFT") {
        d = "RIGHT";
    } else if ((event.key == 'ArrowDown' || event.key == 's' || event.key == 'S') && d != "UP") {
        d = "DOWN";
    }
}

//Snake collision function
function collision(head, array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (head.x == array[i].x && head.y == array[i].y) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}



// Draw function for canvas

function draw() {

    ctx.drawImage(ground, 0, 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, box, box);
    }

    ctx.drawImage(foodImg, food.x, food.y);

    // Snake head position
    var snakeX = snake[0].x;
    var snakeY = snake[0].y;

    //Snake direction 
    if (d == "LEFT") snakeX -= box;
    if (d == "UP") snakeY -= box;
    if (d == "RIGHT") snakeX += box;
    if (d == "DOWN") snakeY += box;

    //Snake eats the food
    if (snakeX == food.x && snakeY == food.y) {
        food = {
            x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 17 + 1) * box,
            y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 15 + 3) * box
        }

    } else {
        //remove snake tail
        snake.pop();
    }

    var updatehead = {
        x: snakeX,
        y: snakeY
    }

    //game over rule

    if (snakeX < box || snakeX > 17 * box || snakeY < 3 * box || snakeY > 17 * box || collision(updatehead, snake)) {
        clearInterval(game);
    }

    snake.unshift(updatehead);
}
// Call draw function

let game = setInterval(draw, 100);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40' viewBox='0 0 40 40'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg fill='%23f9229e' fill-opacity='0.26'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 38.59l2.83-2.83 1.41 1.41L1.41 40H0v-1.41zM0 1.4l2.83 2.83 1.41-1.41L1.41 0H0v1.41zM38.59 40l-2.83-2.83 1.41-1.41L40 38.59V40h-1.41zM40 1.41l-2.83 2.83-1.41-1.41L38.59 0H40v1.41zM20 18.6l2.83-2.83 1.41 1.41L21.41 20l2.83 2.83-1.41 1.41L20 21.41l-2.83 2.83-1.41-1.41L18.59 20l-2.83-2.83 1.41-1.41L20 18.59z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 2% auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 36px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    border: 5px solid #f9229e
}

#container section {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;

}

button {
    background-color: slateblue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Snake</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="Snake" width="608" height="608" data-aos="flip-up">
    </canvas>
    <div id="container">
        <section>
            <button id="retry" type="button">RESTART</button>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you'll want to do is have your button call a function. You can do with that with onclick:

```
<button id="retry" type="button" onclick="restart()">RESTART</button>
```

Here I've named the function `restart` but you can call it whatever you want. Next, you'll want to define a function `restart` in your code:

```
function restart() {
    // Your code will go in here
}
```

The final step is to add anything inside the `restart()` function that you might need to reset the game. For example, you might want to reset the head position:

```
// Just like you did at the top of your code, except
// we don't need "var" again
snake = [];
snake[0] = {
    x: 9 * box,
    y: 10 * box
}
```

You'll also need to restart the interval since you clear it when they lose:

```
// Just in case they hit the button while the game is in-progress!
clearInterval(game)
// Now create the interval again (like you did at the bottom of your code):
game = setInterval(draw, 100)
```

You may also want to reset things such as food position and direction.

Side note, if you want to clean up your code a bit, it's probably worth using the `restart()` function both for restarting, but also starting the game! This way you won't need to have a bunch of duplicate code that initializes the snake, food, direction, etc... Instead, you can just initialize the variables at the top and then at the bottom of your code, call `restart()` to immediately start the game.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this to your page...

```
<a href="">Begin Again</a>
```